# Logging optional key values

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I have this webapplication that logs quite heavily. We have implemented a call to `MDC` for each requesting thread to be able to trace a user in our logs.

A logmessage could look as follows:

```
INFO  [2017-10-09 10:10:55,841] user_uuid=123-123-123 com.myapp.SomeClass: Some log message...
```

Now the problem is that most of the time, no current user exist, and we don't have use for the `user_uuid` field in the log example above. So instead, it will look like this:

```
INFO  [2017-10-09 10:10:55,841] user_uuid= com.myapp.SomeClass: Some log message...
```

**Is there any way of not writing the MDC key & value in log if there is no MDC value? Some log format I haven't found yet?**

I want it to look like this, if no MDC value is found:

```
INFO  [2017-10-09 10:10:55,841] com.myapp.SomeClass: Some log message...
```

The above (MDC) examples are configured like so:

```
%-5p [%d{ISO8601,UTC}] user_uuid=%mdc{user_uuid:-} %c: %m%n%rEx
```

Comment: You could just display the full MDC (this of course requires that you store only important information there), then it would log only the contents that exist. In your example you've hardcoded the `user_uuid=` part, so that's not going to go anywhere.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616745/how-to-conditionally-add-text-from-mdc-on-a-log4j-pattern for a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This entry in your pattern ...

```
user_uuid=%mdc{user_uuid:-}
```

... consists of two parts:

1. A static 'root' (i.e. the left hand side of the assignment) this is always present in the output. The decision to include this is made when Logback initialises itself.
2. A value (i.e. the right hand side of the assignment), this is only present in the output if the MDC attribute `user_uuid` is populated. The decision to include this is made at runtime for each log event.

Probably not telling you anything new there but the key point is that the inclusion of the left hand side cannot be undone by any conditional logic which kicks in when evaluating each log event emitted by your application. Logback's `PatternLayoutBase` walks through its given pattern and each time it comes to something conditional or derivable it evaluates it and appends the evaluated value to the pattern it is walking through. So, for your pattern; Logback has already assigned "user_uuid=" to the current StringBuilder before it even starts evaluating the MDC condition.

However, you *could* achieve the desired end goal by populating the `user_uuid` MDC attribute with: `user_uuid=<the user id>` and then change you logging pattern to simply log the MDC value without the assignment. For example:

```
%-5p [%d{ISO8601,UTC}] %mdc{user_uuid:-}%c: %m%n%rEx
```

With that pattern in place the following log invocations ...

```
logger.info("Does this include the user_uuid?");
MDC.put("user_uuid", "user_uuid=me ");
logger.info("Or does this include the user_uuid?");
```

... will emit:

```
INFO  [2017-10-09 11:15:22,420] com.stackoverflow.SomeClassTest: Does this include the user_uuid?
INFO  [2017-10-09 11:15:22,435] user_uuid=me com.stackoverflow.SomeClassTest: Or does this include the user_uuid?
```

Though that's a bit awkward because you have to remember to include a space at the end of the MDC value and this `user_uuid` MDC value is only useful for logging within this specific pattern (whereas simply including the `user_uuid` - without the left hand side and the equals operator - would be more generally useful).

If these drawbacks render this approach unuseable for you then I think you'll have to get stuck into Logback's `PatternLayoutBase` or `FormattingConverter` to implement some form of look-ahead or some way of amending the in-progress StringBuilder if the right hand side of an assignment returns an empty String.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer! Thank you very much :)
I will create some kind of util class to manage the MDC `put` calls. (Which will wrap them with `key=<val>`

Answer (score 8):

You can use `%replace` to replace `user_uuid=` with an empty string if the value is missing (note the trailing `$` in the regex, meaning "end of input"):

```
%-5p [%d{ISO8601,UTC}]%replace( user_uuid=%mdc{user_uuid}){' user_uuid=$', ''} %c: %m%n%rEx
```

As a bonus, the above will also remove the leading space if the value is missing, so you don't get two successive spaces in your log message if the value is missing.

Comment: That's a really nice and almost elegant hack that actually achieves the end goal

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Alin Sînpălean response, this hack will also help with trailing spaces,

```
[text before]%replace( %X{any_key} ){'  ', ' '}[text after]
```

Note the two empty spaces wrapping the expression in `%replace( %X{any_key} )`

if the variable is empty, the double space will be replaced by a single one, so it looks consistent:

```
[text before] [text after]
```

And it will be properly spaced if it contains anything

```
[text before] content [text after]
```